# Want to know if this is the right solution to the following question

Tags: linear-algebra

I just want to know if this is the right answer
Given $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
      2&0&0\\
1&3&0\\
1&1&1
\end{pmatrix} , b = \begin{pmatrix}
      b_1\\
b_2\\
b_3
\end{pmatrix}$$

A)Write the linear system corresponding to $Ax = b$:
\begin{align*}
x_1 &= b_1\\
x_2 &= b_2+b_1\\
x_3 &= b_3+b_2+b_1
\end{align*}
B)Solve the linear equation
\begin{align*}
b_1 &= 2\\
x_2 &= 4\\
x_3 &= 3
\end{align*}

C)Find the inverse of matrix A
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
      2&0&0\\
3&1&0\\
1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: No. They are not correct.

Comment: So is it suppose to be x1 = b1,x2=b1+b2 and x3 = b1+b2+b3

Comment: Which parts are wrong?

Comment: Hmm... all the parts are wrong. DonAntonio has helped you with part A. In part b, try to express $x_i$ in terms of linear combination of $b_j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have (if I understood correctly your symbols):

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\1&3&0\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix}\iff \begin{cases}&2x_1&=b_1\\&x_1+3x_2&=b_2\\&x_1+x_2+x_3&=b_3\end{cases}$$

Try now to calculate the inverse of $\;A\;$, and observe that $\;\det A=6\;$

**Added on request**: Observe that we have

$$\text{First line:}\;\;2x_1=b_1\implies x_1=\frac{b_1}2$$

and now

$$\text{Second line:}\;\;\frac{b_1}2+3x_2=b_2\implies x_2=\frac{b_2-\frac{b_1}2}3$$

and etc.

Comment: Still don't understand part b. I thought that I just add the results from part a and that should be my answer to part b.

Comment: @user263146 HAve you studied matrix reduction, Gauss method and etc.? Iin this case it is even easier as your coefficients matrix is upper triangular, so you can begin solving directy

Comment: @user263146 Check what I added to my answer.